# Prop search tied to particle system (pointer property is read-only)

Tags: python, properties

I'm trying to register an object pointer to type ParticleSystem, so that I can use it for a prop_search, but the pointer is set to read-only by default, which causes an error. Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
def register():
  bpy.types.ParticleSystem.my_pointer = bpy.types.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object, name="My Pointer")

def draw_panel(self, context):
  for ps in context.object.particle_systems:
    box = layout.box()
    box.prop(ps, "name")
    box.prop_search(ps, "my_pointer", context.scene, "objects", icon="OBJECT_DATA", text="target object")
```

The boxes and particle system names are rendered, but the prop_search throws an error and isn't rendered.

Here is the error:

```
<_PropertyDeferred, <built-in function PointerProperty>, {'type': <class 'bpy_types.Object'>, 'name': 'My Pointer'}>
rna_uiItemPointerR: property not found: ParticleSystem.my_pointer
```

If I try to set the value of the pointer in the console it tells me that the property is read-only.

Is there a workaround for this? How can I have an object pointer that is unique for each particle system? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on particle system names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual section for [Property Definitions](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#assigning-to-existing-classes) says

> Custom properties can be added to any subclass of an ID, Bone and PoseBone.

but [`bpy.types.ParticleSystem`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html) only inherits from [`bpy.struct`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ParticleSystem.html) and that doesn't inherit from any of the allowed classes.

So your code is failing because you can't add a property to the particle system type.

Comment: So there is no way to identify particle systems other than name or index?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  But perhaps you could edit your question and explain what it is you want the identifier for and why the name or index won't do.